# Mobile website redirect, Full Site link, without cookie. Cookie seems to prevent return to mobile site

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I'm testing a few JavaScripts that redirect mobile users from a main website to a mobile website.  What I have found uses cookies however, and the cookies seem to prevent returning users from going directly back to the mobile website, without clearing the browser's cookies, not just closing browser.

Can I do this with a variable instead of a cookie?  Or PHP?

This simple script looks like it uses use a file value stored, but I can't get it to work.

```
<script>
if (document.location.search.indexOf("skipmobile") >= 0) {
document.cookie = "skipmobile=1";
}
else if ((document.location.hostname.match(/\.mobi$/) || screen.width < 699)
&& document.cookie.indexOf("skipmobile") == -1)
{
document.location = "mobile/";
}
</script>`
```

Mobile side link to full site has this ending:
    http://www.domain.com/?skipmobile=1`

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with `going directly back to the mobile website`? You mean when the user closes the browser and opens your webpage again, then the user sees the desktop version of your webpage again?

Answer (score 0):

I chanced upon this article that you have, I am Neil and I work for handsetdetection.com. Just to let everyone of your reader know that there is also another way of redirecting your viewer to a mobile site that you have and automatically adjust the screen size and buttons to whatever type of mobile device they are using. However, having a mobile version of your site is not enough, you have to redirect your visitors from your main website to a mobile version of your site. It is called handsetdetection and it is quite easy to install as a plug in to any back end of your site. 
Hope this helps, 
Neil Summers